# Get mapping.txt file from the Proguard (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mapping, proguard

After the release build I'd like to get mapping.txt file which could be done with Proguard.
I have proguard.cfg (BuildAction is set to ProguardConfiguration) file added to the project with next content:

```
-dontobfuscate
-ignorewarnings
-keep class... 
...
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

Please advice what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll not get a mapping.txt when building Xamarin Android apps, even if you try to force that with custom configuration.

[From docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows#overview):

> Obfuscation step – In native Android development, ProGuard renames
>   classes and class members that are not entry points. Retaining entry
>   points ensures that they can still be accessed by their original
>   names. **However, this step is not supported by Xamarin.Android because
>   the app is compiled down to Intermediate Language (IL)**.

....

> In fact, it is not possible to enable obfuscation through ProGuard
>   (even through the use of custom configuration files)

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions

1. Remove the -dontobfuscate from your configuration file, if proguard is not obfuscating anything then there won't be a mapping file.
2. What I remember proguard look for proguard.conf file by default, if you are using some other names, you also need to tell proguard the file name( I could be wrong here)